# jQuery waypoints plugin - remove class when out of view

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using waypoints plugin

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
    jQuery(".block7").addClass("active");
});
```

Now I want to modify it to make the added class removed from the `.thing` element immediately when its out of browser view. What do I add to code above?

Comment: Could you make a demo for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by looking at `direction`. If the same offset works for both adding and removing the class, you can put this in your handler

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.thing'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'up') {
      $(".block7").removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".block7").addClass("active");
    }
  },
  offset: '100%'
})
```

Or if you want different offsets, you can make 2 waypoints.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.thing'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    $(".block7").addClass("active");
  },
  offset: '75%'
})

var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.thing'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'up') {
      $(".block7").removeClass("active");
    }
  },
  offset: '100%'
})
```

Here's a codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZqMdJ

Comment: I tested it, thanks. how do i make it removed when the page scrolled down as well?

Comment: i tried     if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') 
 it didnt work

Comment: @Pavel I would encourage trying to figure it out on your own. FYI I've never used waypoints before, just read the docs for  your question, it seems like a simple library. If you can't figure it out, make a new post.

Comment: i read before.  i mean it suppose to be simple. just adding down. but it doesnt work -  if (direction == 'up';) {
      $(".menu-item-939").removeClass("subactive");
    }

     else if (direction == 'down';) {
      $(".menu-item-939").removeClass("subactive");
    }

     else {
      $(".menu-item-939").addClass("subactive");
    }

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using an additional waypoint that tests for the direction being equal to down AND uses a negative offset for when to trigger the handler. The negative offset is the key to getting this to work when the item is out of the browser view.

```
var resetWaypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.thing'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
      $(".block7").removeClass("active");
    } 
  },
  offset: '-10%'. /* where the magic happens. play with # til it works correctly with size of your element. */
})
```

Bigger picture though - if you're trying to essentially reset the waypoint so that every time the user scrolls past it, either going up or down, you can fade in/fade out something, you'll want to look into the 'inview' settings. More information here:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/inview/